# When should I use scons scanner vs parseDepends and Depends

Tags: scons

My apologies for this long question.

*The following is what I would like to do  with scons*

- Build a java component **before** a grammar files component (it is a voice-recognition project).  My grammar files component needs the java component for his own compilation.
- Using multi-processing (-j)

*What is working so far :*

- 95% of our c++ code is being built perfectly with scons -j4.  Dependcies tree is properly created
- Our custom python builder generates the .jar from java component with ant

*What is NOT working :*

- Our custom python builder to generate binaries from grammar files component is being called BEFORE the java compilation when using -j4.

The following is the scons script file that generate sideLibrary.jar (using Command)

```
Import('common_env')
#Grab a copy of the top environment (the one sent by the SConstruct file)
common_env = common_env.Clone()
#Current working directory.
currentDir = common_env['ENV']['LOCALROOT'] + '/' + common_env.sconsGetCWD()
#Launches ant -q
tgts = common_env.Command(target = [currentDir + '/dist', currentDir + '/dialogeditor/lib', currentDir + '/doc/sdtk', currentDir + '/obj', common_env['ENV']['LOCALROOT'] + '/LINK/bin/win32/sideLibrary.jar'], source = 'build.xml', action = 'ant -q -f $SOURCE')
#Cleans the generated folders
common_env.Clean(tgts, '')
```

The following is the scons script file to generate the grammar binary files (using custom builder) :

```
Import('common_env')
#Creates a copy of the build environment sent from the SConstruct file.
common_env = common_env.Clone()
#Because this component is only compiled in win32
if (common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] == "win32"):
    #Language of the grammar.
    common_env['ENV']['LANGUAGE'] = 'en'
    #Language pack.
    common_env['ENV']['LANGUAGE_PACK'] = 'English.America.3.3.0'
    #Grammar name
    common_env['ENV']['GRAMMAR_NAME'] = 'faa'
    #Compiles the grammar using a custom builder.
    common_env.buildGrammar(src = common_env['ENV']['LOCALROOT'] + '/LINK/bin/win32/sideLibrary.jar')
```

Someone told me that passing *src = common_env['ENV']['LOCALROOT'] + '/LINK/bin/win32/sideLibrary.jar'* to our custom builder tells scons that he MUST automagically wait fro sideLibrary.jar before calling buildGrammar.  I really have doubts because the [doc](http://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user.html#idp1397485612) only says :

> source: A list of Node objects representing the sources to be used by
>   this builder function to build the targets.

That brings me to [Scanner](http://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-scanners), [ParseDepens](http://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user.html#idp1396741444) and [Depends](http://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user.html#idp1396736388) (I already read scons documentation about them).

It is not really clear in my mind which one I should use to accomplish what I want to do : force compilation of java component BEFORE another component with -j4.

Could someone can light my lantern please?

Thank you

**EDIT**
*(added dependency tree)*

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
copyAction(["LINK\bin\win32\msvcp100d.dll", "LINK\bin\win32\msvcr100d.dll", "LINK\bin\win32\mfc100d.dll", "LINK\bin\win32\mfc100ud.dll", "LINK\bin\win32\rdbgsetup_x86.exe"], ["C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugCRT\msvcp100d.dll", "C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugCRT\msvcr100d.dll", "C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugMFC\mfc100d.dll", "C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugMFC\mfc100ud.dll", "C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\RemoteDebugger\rdbgsetup_x86.exe"])
ant -q -f sr\side\build.xml
buildGrammar(["LINK\data\Grammars\src\grammars\AvailableCommand.xml", "sr\sra\src\grammars\en\faa\faa.autopron", "sr\sra\src\grammars\en\faa\faa.missing", "sr\sra\src\grammars\en\faa\faa.functions"], [])
+-.
  +-build
  | +-build\debug
  |   +-build\debug\sr
  |     +-build\debug\sr\side
  |     | +-build\debug\sr\side\win32
  |     |   +-sr\side\build.xml
  |     |   +-sr\side\side.sc
  |     +-build\debug\sr\sra
  |       +-build\debug\sr\sra\src
  |         +-build\debug\sr\sra\src\grammars
  |           +-build\debug\sr\sra\src\grammars\win32
  |             +-sr\sra\src\grammars\src_grammars.sc
  +-c
  +-cm
  | +-cm\sconsUtilities
  +-LINK
  | +-LINK\bin
  | | +-LINK\bin\win32
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\mfc100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugCRT\msvcp100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugCRT\msvcr100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugMFC\mfc100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugMFC\mfc100ud.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\RemoteDebugger\rdbgsetup_x86.exe
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\mfc100ud.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugCRT\msvcp100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugCRT\msvcr100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugMFC\mfc100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugMFC\mfc100ud.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\RemoteDebugger\rdbgsetup_x86.exe
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\msvcp100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugCRT\msvcp100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugCRT\msvcr100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugMFC\mfc100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugMFC\mfc100ud.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\RemoteDebugger\rdbgsetup_x86.exe
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\msvcr100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugCRT\msvcp100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugCRT\msvcr100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugMFC\mfc100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugMFC\mfc100ud.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\RemoteDebugger\rdbgsetup_x86.exe
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\rdbgsetup_x86.exe
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugCRT\msvcp100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugCRT\msvcr100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugMFC\mfc100d.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugMFC\mfc100ud.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\Microsoft_Visual_Studio_10.0\RemoteDebugger\rdbgsetup_x86.exe
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\sideLibrary.jar
  | |     +-sr\side\build.xml
  | |     +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin\ant.BAT
  | +-LINK\data
  |   +-LINK\data\Grammars
  |     +-LINK\data\Grammars\src
  |       +-LINK\data\Grammars\src\grammars
  |         +-LINK\data\Grammars\src\grammars\AvailableCommand.xml
  +-SConstruct
  +-sr
    +-sr\side
    | +-sr\side\build.xml
    | +-sr\side\dialogeditor
    | | +-sr\side\dialogeditor\lib
    | |   +-sr\side\build.xml
    | |   +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin\ant.BAT
    | +-sr\side\dist
    | | +-sr\side\build.xml
    | | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin\ant.BAT
    | +-sr\side\doc
    | | +-sr\side\doc\sdtk
    | |   +-sr\side\build.xml
    | |   +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin\ant.BAT
    | +-sr\side\obj
    | | +-sr\side\build.xml
    | | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\devTool\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin\ant.BAT
    | +-sr\side\side.sc
    +-sr\sra
      +-sr\sra\src
        +-sr\sra\src\grammars
          +-sr\sra\src\grammars\en
          | +-sr\sra\src\grammars\en\faa
          |   +-sr\sra\src\grammars\en\faa\faa.autopron
          |   +-sr\sra\src\grammars\en\faa\faa.functions
          |   +-sr\sra\src\grammars\en\faa\faa.missing
          +-sr\sra\src\grammars\src_grammars.sc
scons: done building targets.
```

**EDIT 2** *added buildGrammar*

```
def buildGrammar(target, source, env):
    LANGUAGE = env['ENV']['LANGUAGE']
    LANGUAGE_PACK = env['ENV']['LANGUAGE_PACK']
    GRAMMAR_NAME = env['ENV']['GRAMMAR_NAME']
    LINKD = env['ENV']['LINKD']
    SIDE_BINARY_DIR = LINKD + '/bin/win32'
    DATAPACK_OUT_UDIR = DATAPACK_OUT_DIR = LINKD
    GRAMMAR_SRC_DIR = env['ENV']['LOCALROOT'] + '/sr/sra/src/grammars/' + LANGUAGE + '/' + GRAMMAR_NAME
    GRAMMAR_SRC_FILES = glob.glob(GRAMMAR_SRC_DIR + '/*.grammar') + glob.glob(GRAMMAR_SRC_DIR + '/*.dictionary')
    CUSTOM_NL_FUNCTIONS_FILE = GRAMMAR_SRC_DIR + '/' + GRAMMAR_NAME + '.functions'
    PBS_FILE = env['ENV']['LOCALROOT'] + '/fwk/systemInterface/simnet/src/pbs_api.h'
    SIDE_LIBRARY_PATH = SIDE_BINARY_DIR + '/sideLibrary.jar'
    SRROOT = env['ENV']['LOCALROOT'] + '/sr'
    GRM_PROJECT = 'faa'
    UTIL_DIR = env['ENV']['LOCALROOT'] + '/sr/sra/utils/build'
    #CUSTOM_NL_FUNCTIONS_FILE
    print "(+) Generating " + CUSTOM_NL_FUNCTIONS_FILE
    customNlFunctionsFile = open(CUSTOM_NL_FUNCTIONS_FILE, "w")
    call("perl " + UTIL_DIR + '/header2Nuance ' + PBS_FILE, stdout = customNlFunctionsFile) 
    customNlFunctionsFile.close()
    print "Done."
    #dataPackBuild
    print "(+) Building lexix datapack... (no find and no chmod) - Grammar"
    if os.path.exists(DATAPACK_OUT_UDIR + '/data/Grammars/abnf/bin/' + GRAMMAR_NAME):
        shutil.rmtree(DATAPACK_OUT_UDIR + '/data/Grammars/abnf/bin/' + GRAMMAR_NAME)
    if os.path.exists(DATAPACK_OUT_UDIR + '/data/SOURCES'):
        shutil.rmtree(DATAPACK_OUT_UDIR + '/data/SOURCES')
    linkToWD = env['ENV']['LOCALROOT'] + '/sr/sra/src/grammars'
    os.chdir(linkToWD)
    call('java -jar ' + SIDE_LIBRARY_PATH + ' --verbyx -l ' + SIDE_BINARY_DIR + '/plugin.properties ' + '--deploy . ' + DATAPACK_OUT_DIR + ' > /dev/nul')
    if not os.path.exists(DATAPACK_OUT_UDIR + '/data/Grammars/src/grammars/en/faa'):
        os.makedirs(DATAPACK_OUT_UDIR + '/data/Grammars/src/grammars/en/faa')
    for file in GRAMMAR_SRC_FILES:
        shutil.copy(file, DATAPACK_OUT_UDIR + '/data/Grammars/src/grammars/en/faa')
    for file in glob.glob('*.xml'):
        shutil.copy(file, DATAPACK_OUT_UDIR + '/data/Grammars/src/grammars')
    shutil.copy('.project', DATAPACK_OUT_UDIR + '/data/Grammars/src/grammars')
    copytree('./project', DATAPACK_OUT_UDIR + '/data/Grammars/src/grammars/project')
    copytree('./.settings', DATAPACK_OUT_UDIR + '/data/Grammars/src/grammars/.settings')
    os.chdir(env['ENV']['LOCALROOT'])
    print "Done."

    #grammar.mk
    DATA_DIR = env['ENV']['LOCALROOT'] + '/LINK/data'
    GRAMMAR_SRC_DIR = SRROOT + '/sra/src/grammars'
    GRAMMAR_PROJECT_SRC_DIR = GRAMMAR_SRC_DIR + '/en/' + GRM_PROJECT
    GRAMMAR_OBJ_DIR = DATA_DIR + '/Grammars/bin'
    OUTPUT_DIR = GRAMMAR_OBJ_DIR + '/' + LANGUAGE + '/' + GRM_PROJECT
    AD_HOME = 'C:/Adacel/temp'
    PROJECT_DICTIONARY = DATA_DIR + '/Grammars/bin/dictionary'
    PROJECT_SRC_DICTIONARY = GRM_PROJECT + '.dictionary'
    PROJECT_OUT_DICTIONARY = OVERRIDE_OUT_DICTIONARY = PROJECT_DICTIONARY + '/' + LANGUAGE_PACK
    PROJECT_OUT_DIST_DICTIONARY = OVERRIDE_OUT_DIST_DICTIONARY = AD_HOME + '/nuance/dictionary/' + LANGUAGE_PACK
    PROJECT_SRC_OVR_DICTIONARY = OVR_DICTIONARY = 'override.dictionary'
    GRAMMAR_MASTER_FILE = GRM_PROJECT + '.grammar'
    COMPILE_FLAGS = LANGUAGE_PACK + ' -auto_pron -optimize_graph -dont_flatten -node_array_optimization_level FULL -override_dictionary ' + OVERRIDE_OUT_DIST_DICTIONARY + '/' + OVR_DICTIONARY + ' -merge_dictionary ' + PROJECT_OUT_DIST_DICTIONARY + '/' + PROJECT_SRC_DICTIONARY
    print "(+) Merging " + PROJECT_OUT_DICTIONARY + " and " + PROJECT_OUT_DIST_DICTIONARY
    if not os.path.exists(PROJECT_OUT_DICTIONARY):
        os.makedirs(PROJECT_OUT_DICTIONARY)
    shutil.copy(SRROOT + '/sra/src/grammars/' + LANGUAGE + '/' + GRM_PROJECT + '/' + PROJECT_SRC_DICTIONARY, PROJECT_OUT_DICTIONARY)
    if not os.path.exists(PROJECT_OUT_DIST_DICTIONARY):
        os.makedirs(PROJECT_OUT_DIST_DICTIONARY)
    shutil.copy(SRROOT + '/sra/src/grammars/' + LANGUAGE + '/' + GRM_PROJECT + '/' + PROJECT_SRC_DICTIONARY, PROJECT_OUT_DIST_DICTIONARY)
    print "Done."
    print "Copying " + OVERRIDE_OUT_DICTIONARY + " and " + OVERRIDE_OUT_DIST_DICTIONARY
    if not os.path.exists(OVERRIDE_OUT_DICTIONARY):
        os.makedirs(OVERRIDE_OUT_DICTIONARY)
    shutil.copy(SRROOT + '/sra/src/grammars/' + LANGUAGE + '/' + GRM_PROJECT + '/' + PROJECT_SRC_OVR_DICTIONARY, PROJECT_OUT_DICTIONARY)
    if not os.path.exists(OVERRIDE_OUT_DIST_DICTIONARY):
        os.makedirs(OVERRIDE_OUT_DIST_DICTIONARY)
    shutil.copy(SRROOT + '/sra/src/grammars/' + LANGUAGE + '/' + GRM_PROJECT + '/' + PROJECT_SRC_OVR_DICTIONARY, OVERRIDE_OUT_DIST_DICTIONARY)
    print "Done."
    NUANCE_COMPILER = env['ENV']['NUANCE_ROOT'] + '/bin/win32/nuance-compile '
    #Compiles Grammar.
    if not os.path.exists(OUTPUT_DIR + '/' + LANGUAGE_PACK):
        os.makedirs(OUTPUT_DIR + '/' + LANGUAGE_PACK)
    print "(+) Building " + LANGUAGE + "." + GRM_PROJECT + "." + LANGUAGE_PACK + " grammar..."
    os.chdir(env['ENV']['LOCALROOT'] + '/sr/sra/src/grammars/' + LANGUAGE + '/' + GRM_PROJECT)
    compilationCmd = NUANCE_COMPILER + GRAMMAR_MASTER_FILE + ' ' + COMPILE_FLAGS + ' -o ' + OUTPUT_DIR + '/' + LANGUAGE_PACK + ' -write_auto_pron_output ' + OUTPUT_DIR + '/' + LANGUAGE_PACK + '/.missing'
    call(compilationCmd)
    os.chdir(env['ENV']['LOCALROOT'])
    print "Done."

    #Grammar-database.mk
    print "(+) Creating dynamic grammar database (" + LANGUAGE + ")..."
    GRAMMAR_DIR = env['ENV']['LOCALROOT'] + '/LINK/data/Grammars/bin'
    GRAMMAR_DATABASE_DIR = GRAMMAR_DIR + '/' + LANGUAGE + '/dgdb-common'
    if os.path.exists(GRAMMAR_DATABASE_DIR):
        shutil.rmtree(GRAMMAR_DATABASE_DIR)
    if not os.path.exists(GRAMMAR_DIR + '/' + LANGUAGE):
        os.makedirs(GRAMMAR_DIR + '/' + LANGUAGE)
    NUANCE_DATABASE = env['ENV']['NUANCE_ROOT'] + '/bin/win32/nuance-database-admin '
    DB_FLAGS = '-dboperation create -dbname common -dbprovider fs -dbclass dgdb -dbroot ' + GRAMMAR_DIR + '/' + LANGUAGE
    call(NUANCE_DATABASE + DB_FLAGS)
    print "Done."
    return None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not sure this question will ever help someone, but I feel important to at least answer my question.

So, to everyone starting with scons, always use *"source="* as function parameter.  All my problem (-j4 not working), was completely related with the fact that when I was calling my custom builder, I was using it like that *"buildGrammar(src="blabla")"*.  It is wrong.  Must be *"buildGrammar(source="blabla")*

Answer (score 1):

You probably need neither of `Scanner`, `ParseDepends` or `Depends`. Please have a look at our [ToolsForFools Guide](https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/ToolsForFools) and check out how to provide an `Emitter` for your Builder.

What SCons needs to know is, that the file `sideLibrary.jar` is created by another Builder in the system (the whole build description). If you have specified `sideLibrary.jar` as a target of the creating Builder explicitly already, this should work out of the box. SCons then knows that `sideLibrary.jar` is both, a target of one Builder and the source file for another one. So it can schedule the single build steps correctly...

However, if your `sideLibrary.jar` is only the byproduct of another build command:

```
env.YourBuilder('other.jar', Glob('*.java'))
```

, then you need to define a special Emitter for this type of build, such that SCons can see the connection between building `other.jar` and creating `sideLibrary.jar` at the same time.

I hope this makes things clearer for you. If you still struggle with getting it to work, please come to our UserMailing list (`scons-users@scons.org`, see also http://scons.org/lists.html) where we can discuss your problem in much greater detail and you'll probably get even more helpful reference pointers into our documentation.

Comment: You said  in your reply above "_If you have specified sideLibrary.jar as a target of the creating Builder_ " I think it might be my problem.  If you look at my post, I added scons script for my java component.  I did not specify sideLibrary.jar as target anywhere.  In which scons script should I add this target?  thx...

Comment: You have to specify it as target for the Builder which is responsible for creating `sideLibrary.jar`...I don't see this step anywhere in your example above, so I can't exactly tell you which line should get amended and how.

Comment: Oh wait, at reading it a second time I see that you also gave the SConscript for the `sideLibrary.jar`...and the target specification there looks correct. My guess is now that your problems are based on your usage of `currentDir`. Is  `common_env['ENV']['LOCALROOT']` an absolute or relative path?

Comment: common_env['ENV']['LOCALROOT'] is absolute

Comment: Please ensure that the dependencies are correct: replace the call of your `buildGrammar` builder with `common_env.Install('install', common_env['ENV']['LOCALROOT'] + '/LINK/bin/win32/sideLibrary.jar'`. Does this work, or is the `Install` complaining that the file can't be found? You can also check the dependency tree with the `--tree=all|derive|prune` option (see [our MAN page](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html))...

Comment: I forgot to add: after replacing the Builder call with Install, remove the file `sideLibrary.jar` and rerun SCons again...such that a rebuild of the JAR file is actually required. Other question: where exactly does the absolute path in `common_env['ENV']['LOCALROOT']` point to? Is it a folder outside of your SCons top-level folder? In the latter case you may be trapped by number 2 of our "most frequently asked" FAQs (check out the top of our FAQ list at https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions ).

Comment: 1-Replacing `buildGrammar()` by `Install()` actually worked with `scons -j4` (after `scons -c` to remove `sideLibrary.jar`). I can clearly see that `Install` is invoke after `sideLibrary` is created. 2-`common_env['ENV']['LOCALROOT']` point inside Scons top level folder. 3-I printed dependency tree, see my edit.  Looks ok to me.

Comment: Then the error must be related to your `buildGrammar` method/builder. How does it look like? The dependency tree is *not* okay like this, because it lists your `sideLibrary.jar` only once...as target of the `ant.BAT` action. But there should be another entry, as source to your grammar builder...so that's where the culprit seems to be.

Comment: @ dirkbaechle  Added `buildGrammar`.  This function is a mess.  We are currently moving from make system to scons.  This function might looks like really make centric.  I would be glad if you are able to find something in this mess :S

Comment: I'm noticing this only right now: you're specifying the source list for your `buildGrammar` Builder with the `src=` keyword...but this should actually be `source=`. This typo would explain the error that you see pretty well.

Comment: OMG.  I mean, I feel bad that you wasted your time to answer this question.  It WORKED now.  Thank you so much and sorry again...